# regex to get rid of special characters and getting rid of the space that it left

Tags: oracle

is there a way to get rid of the spaces after getting rid of the special characters in regex?

For example, if I do

```
Select REGEXP_REPLACE
  ('Test¥ÇÂ\est1_^_\L¢\L\this is a test', '[^0-9A-Za-z\-\@\<\>\(\)\"\,\/\]', ' ')  test
from dual;
```

this will result in: `Test   \est1   \L \L\this is a test`

I want results to show without the spaces where it replaced the special characters, but not between regular words like this:

```
Test\est1\L\L\this is a test
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the space in the pattern as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
  2      'Test¥ÇÂ\est1_^_\L¢\L\this is a test',
  3      '[^0-9A-Za-z-@\<>()\"\,/ ]',
  4      ''
  5  ) TEST
  6    FROM DUAL;

TEST
-----------------------------
TestA\est1\L\L\this is a test

SQL>
```